# The help systems return "help provider not available"

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code to program in R and I have recently had trouble using the `?func` and `??func` command.
When typing something like `?rnorm`, the message `Couldn't show help for path: /library/stats/html/Normal.html`  shows up. The path is there and I'm sure R is in the path environment. This is really boggling me.

When I first installed R it was working absolutely fine in VSC but now it does not work. However the function works in the R shell. When I try to navigate to the R extension and click on "Help Topics by Package" it says help provider not available.

The packages/html files are there, but VSC doesn't want to access them.

Please advise what I can do to solve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same issue by checking my environmental variables. The steps I followed:

- I added the bin installation file (`C:\R\R-4.1.3\bin` in my case, or `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.3\bin`) to the `path` in my user environmental variables. If you have an admin account, then you have to add the bin folder to the system environmental variables.
- Check if you can start a R console from any terminal.
- If that is positive, then in the Rpath settings for the R extension in vscode write `r`, or in the `settings.json`: `"r.rpath.windows":"r"`
- Restart vscode. Check if the help pages are working.

Hope this helps ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I googled and tried different things and this works for me:

You need to provide the Rpath for the system you are using in the settings for the vscode R package. For example, for a windows machine, you need `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.3\bin\x64\R.exe` there if you installed the latest R using the default settings, and similarly for other systems.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing the [R Language Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r).